# Nodejs `fs.createReadStream` as promise

Tags: node.js, fs

Im trying to get `fs.createReadStream` working as a promise, so after the entire file has been read, it will be resolved.

In the case bellow, im pausing the stream, executing the awaitable method and resuming.

1. How to make `.on('end'...` to be be executed in the end.
2. if 1. is not possible, why the  `.on('wont be fired', maybe i can use it to resolve the promise.

```
function parseFile<T>(filePath: string, row: (x: T) => void, err: (x) => void, end: (x) => void) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
            stream.on('data', async data => {
                    try {
                        stream.pause();
                        await row(data);
                    } finally {
                        stream.resume();
                    }
                })
                .on('end', (rowCount: number) => {
                    resolve();// NOT REALLY THE END row(data) is still being called after this
                })
                .on('close', () => {
                    resolve();// NEVER BEING CALLED
                })
                .on('error', (rowCount: number) => {
                    reject();// NEVER GETS HERE, AS EXPECTED
                })
        })
}
```

**UPDATE**
Here you can actually test it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-czktjh?file=index.js

run `node index.js`

The output should be 1000 and not 1

Thanks

Comment: One of the possible problems here is that you're pausing the input stream, not the csv parse stream.  The `.on('data', ...)` comes from the csv stream so you're NOT pausing that.

Comment: Keep in mind that a single chunk of data from the readStream could result in multiple lines of csv and thus multiple `data` events from the csv stream.  You will also have to test if the csv stream pays attention to the stream pause.  Some streams do, some don't.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks, Im creating a public container so you can run it, removing the pipe did not help

Comment: @jfriend00 - Please see my update

Comment: In your simplified code that you've edited your question to, I cannot reproduce the problem you describe.

Comment: @jfriend00 what about the output. He is got a point. 1 instead of 1000 ....

Comment: @AviFatal - I've posted an answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to be aware of.  You've removed the line processing from the current version of the question so the stream is being read in large chunks.  It appears to be reading the entire file in just two chunks, thus just two `data` events so the expected count here is 2, not 1000.

I think the problem with this code occurs because `stream.pause()` does not pause the generation of the `end` event - it only pauses future `data` events.  If the last `data` event has been fired and you then `await` inside the processing of that `data` event (which causes your `data` event handler to immediately return a promise, the stream will think it's done and the `end` event will still fire before you're done awaiting the function inside the processing of that last `data` event.  Remember, the data event handler is NOT promise-aware.  And, it appears that `stream.pause()` only affects `data` events, not the `end` event.

I can imagine a work-around with a flag that keeps track of whether you're still processing a data event and postpones processing the `end` event until you're done with that last `data` event.  I will add code for that in a second that illustrates how to use the flag.

FYI, the missing `close` event is another stream weirdness.  Your nodejs program actually terminates before the `close` event gets to fire.  If you put this at the start of your program:

```
setTimeout(() => { console.log('done with timer');}, 5000);
```

Then, you will see the close event because the timer will prevent your nodejs program from exiting before the close event gets to fire.  I'm not suggesting this as a solution to any problem, just to illustrate that the `close` event is still there and wants to fire if your program doesn't exit before it gets a chance.

---

Here's code that demonstrated the use of flags to work-around the pause issue.  When you run this code, you will only see 2 `data` events, not 1000 because this code is not reading lines, it's reading much larger chunks that that.  So, the expected result of this is not 1000.

```
// run `node index.js` in the terminal
const fs = require('fs');

const parseFile = row => {
  let  paused = true;
  let ended = false;
  let dataCntr = 0;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const stream = fs.createReadStream('./generated.data.csv');
    stream
      .on('data', async data => {
        ++dataCntr;
        try {
          stream.pause();
          paused = true;
          await row(data);
        } finally {
          paused = false;
          stream.resume();
          if (ended) {
            console.log(`received ${dataCntr} data events`);
            resolve();
          }
        }
      })
      .on('end', rowCount => {
        ended = true;
        if (!paused) {
          console.log(`received ${dataCntr} data events`);
          resolve();
        }
      })
      .on('close', () => {
        //resolve();
      })
      .on('error', rowCount => {
        reject();
      });
  });
};
(async () => {
  let count = 0;
  await parseFile(async row => {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 50)); //sleep
    count++;
  });
  console.log(`lines executed: ${count}, the expected is more than 1`);
})();
```

---

FYI, I still think your original version of the question had the problem I mentioned in my first comment - that you weren't pausing the right stream.  What is documented here is yet another problem (where you can get `end` before your `await` in the last `data` event is done).